# Is it wrong for a Muslimah to address her husband by his name?

Tags: sharia, family

Here, in the Indian sub-continent, it is considered wrong for a Muslim woman to address her husband by his name. So she may *not* address him by his name like, say (assuming the man's name is Abdullah), "Ya Abdullah," though she may call him by his kunniyat like "Ya Abu Ammar" (assuming that their son's name is Ammar). Personally, I don't think there's anything wrong with a woman addressing her husband by his own name, rather than his kunniyat.

I assume that the Umm-ul-Momineen may have addressed the Messenger of Allah (SAWS) by his title and not his name owing to his status. Therefore, that leaves us with the practice of the Companions (RAA). Is there any proof for either argument from the Companions (RAA) of the Messenger of Allah (SAWS)?

Comment: There is no problem with that you can adress by his name

Comment: @Najeeb, as dear Haidar remarked, there is no problem about that. But as a good suggestion; for instance (many of Iranians) endeavor to address their husbands by addition the word MR. Namely: call: Mr.Mohammad ... (as a respectful way of calling. . .) which automatically make the relationship more respected ....  / Even many husbands address their wives as Mrs such as Mrs...   / Finally, I indeed appraciate your admirable and profitable question . . . Jazak Allah Khaira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine for a woman to call her husband by his name as long as he approves it. But of course, if the husband wants the wife to call him by any other name that he likes, then the wife should do so.

Source: http://islamqa.info/en/21532

> There is nothing wrong with a woman calling her husband by his name,
>   because there is no evidence to indicate that that is not allowed. But
>   people’s customs and traditions should be taken into account in this
>   matter. If the custom in some land is that a woman should call her
>   husband by his kunya (Abu So and so) for example, and they think that
>   calling him by his name is ill-mannered, or if the husband does not
>   like to be called by his name, then the women should pay attention to
>   that, because she is required to treat her husband well and it is not
>   good treatment to call him in a manner that he dislikes or that is
>   regarded by people as not good.
>
> Each spouse should address the other by the name that he or she likes
>   best, because that brings about love and affection.

Answer (score 3):

Assalam-O-Alaykoum ...

No, there's no need to worry about this, because it doesn't seem to erupt any wrong into the human nor any kind of Shariah's rules, it's preferable i guess from a moralistic point of view, to ask him about the name or the Kunniyat that he love to hear from you, as a kind of obedience to your husband, which give Allah mercy to you, the Prophet PBUH says :

> Ibn Hibbaan narrated that Abu Hurayrah said: The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “If a woman prays her five (daily prayers), fasts her month (Ramadaan), guards her chastity and obeys her husband, it will be said to her: ‘Enter Paradise from whichever of the gates of Paradise you wish.’”

And Allah knows better.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question. I realize too that this question does not fall into the halaal/haraam category, and has more to do with appropriateness, one way or the other. I was expecting some references from the hadith about the wives of the Companions (RAA).

Comment: This might help: http://islamqa.info/en/21532 . According to this, there is no evidence to indicate that it is wrong. And as far as I know, a general rule if Islam is, something is halal as long as it is not declared as haram. But of course, if the husband wants the wife to call him any other name that he likes, then the wife should do so.

Comment: @Najeeb i had referred the Hadith just to clear out that Allah obligates the wife to obey her husband, so on so, it is preferable that the wife do anything that makes her husband happy to chase the mercy of Allah ... And Allah knows better.

Comment: @hbforce, the point I am trying to make is that there are some things that have little to do with halaal or haraam and more to do with what is appropriate. There are always grey areas and this matter seems to be in that category. It's not that the wife will be thrown into the fire of hell for calling her husband by name. I just wanted to know if this question has to do with Islam or if it is purely a cultural thing.

Comment: @user4150, jazakallahu khairan. The link you forwarded answers the question. Can you copy-paste the content of the linked page so that I could mark that as the answer?

Comment: @Najeeb Glad it helped! I posted it as an answer as you said.